# Apache .htaccess proxpass not taking parameter for internal redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rule setup in `.htaccess` but it doesn't do the internal redirect to the `http` url.

I've also tested [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) but it only returns this: `http://website.com:8290/csc-event`

```
RewriteRule ^tracker/csc-event?(.*)$ http://website.com:8290/csc-event?$1 [P]
```

This is the main URL: 
`https://website.com/tracker/csc-event?p=0%3Ajodv6q8w%3AdO9XGf6T4SCq7kz49hEEUwNvmkqR8Wxw&s=0%3Ajodv6q8w%3AHgkFFmKSZqdBB6E2C~F8xBKTHv8CGwbl&v=0%3Ao1UBwg7_rGBtU8MwvaFsCHbWwngjdnbR&e=0%3Ao1UBwg7_rGBtU8MwvaFsCHbWwngjdnbR1&c=joe7ztjt&n=f&f=f&l=http%3A%2F%2Fdeepneurals.com%2F&i=11y&j=k8&k=1&w=mj&h=i9&t=linkClick&u=(sval_linkClick!%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Learn%20More%20!)&x=-k29a4b` on which I'm trying to run the rule

Any idea why it's not working with params? Also, `[QSA, P]` don't work together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^tracker/csc-event$ http://website.com:8290/csc-event [P,QSA]
```

Because the query string is not part of the rewrite, and it's copied as it is if you do not change it.
I just add the [QSA] as a precaution if you change the rule once, but it is not normally necessary in this case.